# Ensuring a single server executes a task

Tags: database-design

I have multiple servers, which need to perform jobs scheduled at given times.

The jobs are defined in a database, with which each server communicates.
I need to ensure that a job is performed by ONLY one server.

So imagine this scenario:

1. A job is scheduled some time T in the future.
2. At T, both servers wake up and execute the following query: `update
   messages set claimedBy = <server_id> where claimedBy = null
   and timeToRun = <the scheduled time> limit 10`
3. Each server executes its jobs and at the end, sets the `processed`
   column to `true`, so that we know it was actually processed (this
   will help when a server crashes etc).

How does this scheme sound? Do you see anything wrong with it?

---

Or maybe it's a better idea to have one server that "coordinates" the others by passing the jobs to them, so that the issue won't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your logic to find and update the records takes place in one transaction, this sounds okay, i.e. no conflicting update by more than one server will take place.

The solution with one coordinating server has a pro and a con. Pro: You can implement some intracate logic to decide which server should get which jobs, if required someday. Con: You are dependent on that one server. The first solution will also work when some servers are down, as long as at least one of them is up.